# How to edit wordpress native gallery's css file?

Tags: css, gallery

I want to edit my gallery's css file. Where do I find it? or Am I override it? PS: I've got 5 different gallery in 5 different page..

Comment: are you using the WordPress inbuilt gallery system or a plugin?

Comment: inbuilt system.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? Just CSS? (If yes, you can target it from your theme's style.css) Or are you looking to totally redo things? Like change the div's or span's it uses?

Comment: just css right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the default gallery CSS, first, unhook the core-defined CSS:

```
add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
```

Then, you can add your own CSS, however you wish - using your Theme `style.css`, or via separate CSS file that you enqueue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the CSS file in the jetpack plugin directory `wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/css/slideshow-shortcode.css`

You can modify this file in place, but if the plugin gets updated there is a chance these will be overwritten.

It would be better to add the rules to your own stylesheet depending on your theme and loading you might need to use `!important` on the rules to ensure they override the rules in the `slideshow-shortcode.css`, or load the stylesheet after the jetpack one, or copy the entire stylesheet into yours and remove the jetpack one from being loaded using `wp_dequeue_style( 'jetpack-slideshow' )` and adding it to your `functions.php`.